# How can I launch a browser with no window frame or tabs/address bar

Tags: windows-7, browser, frame

I am looking for a way to launch Chrome, Firefox, or IE9+ (any one will do) from a script or command line without any window frame, address bar, or tabs section.

Illustration:

[image: OrangeBox]

For instance, I'd like to only be able to see the section that is comprized of the orange box, and the area inside of it.

The horizontal scroll bar won't be an issue (I control the html that will be displayed and I can ensure it won't need to scroll). Ideally I'd like to cut out the vertical scrollbar, but I could live with it if it were shown.

Does anyone know of any tool or script that would allow me to do this on Windows 7?

Comment: If you're writing the HTML, there are ways to make the browser hide the scrollbar through standard CSS. No need to depend on browser flags for it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Internet Explorer

For Internet Explorer you can use `-k` (kiosk mode):

> Starts Internet Explorer in kiosk mode. The browser opens in a maximized window that does not display the address bar, the navigation buttons, or the status bar.

**Example:**

```
iexplore.exe -k http://www.google.com/
```

Read more about this:

- [Internet Explorer Command-Line Options](http://web.archive.org/web/20130505003831/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728(VS.85).aspx) <sup>(native commands)</sup>
- [Open Internet Explorer in Specific Height and Width](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Open-Internet-Explorer-in-d91674ca) <sup>(script)</sup>

---

### Firefox

Firefox command line option `-fullscreen` didn't work for me:

```
"firefox.exe" -url http://superuser.com -fullscreen
```

But the use of [R-kiosk 0.9.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/?src=search) extension by [Kimmo Heinaaro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/6189/) works like a charm.

> Real Kiosk is a Firefox extension that defaults to full screen, disables all menus, toolbars, key commands and right button menus. Alt+Home still takes you home.

Comment: That is nifty and might work for me, is there anyway that I can specify a Height/Width and x/y position for IE to occupy while in this kiosk mode? Ideally I don't want it to occupy the full screen.

Comment: @Tim Updated my answer with the requested solution.

Answer (score 98):

For chrome/chromium it is the `--app=http://address.com` flag.

You would use it by calling `chromium-browser --app=http://some.website.org` or `google-chrome --app=http://www.google.com` or `chrome.exe --app=http://you.get.it` etc.

All available switches: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

EDIT: You might also want to take a look at the `--kiosk` flag.

Comment: [MOG](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/029/disgusted-mother-of-god.png) so many options :D +1

Comment: This hides the address bar and tabs but leaves the window frame (with min/max, and exit buttons) +1 anyhow though got me a lot closer than I got myself.

Comment: @Tim You could try using the --kiosk flag on some versions of chrome/chromium.

Comment: Any idea how I can do this on `macos`/`osx`?

Comment: For Chrome in KIOSK mode add "--user-data-dir=c:\temp" before the "--kiosk". This will hide the title bar close and mineralize  buttons

Comment: Thanks!! this worked for me

Answer (score 8):

for firefox use

```
firefox.exe -chrome http://example.com
```

Works like a charm but it is not a documented command line option.

**Note:** the size of the window is calculated based on the size of the body, make sure you specify the necessary window size in html.

Comment: It is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-chrome_chrome_URL though I'm note sure if it works as OP asks

Comment: It doesn't work as the OP asked. You cannot load a website as the chrome. I have no idea what you meant by "works like a charm" or how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: This is totally unrelated.chrome urls are this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Firefox_Chrome_URLs

Answer (score 7):

This is trivial to do, via the Chrome extension "[Open As Popup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-as-popup/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc)".

> Opens the current Tab as a Popup-Window
>
> This Extension is really simple:  Click on the Icon and the current
>   Tab will be moved to a new Poup-Window. (A Popup-Window is a Window
>   without Navigation- and Tabbar, so it takes much less vertical-space)
>
> You don't know how this could be useful? I use it as example for
>   API-References or Manuals which I use beside or overlapping my Editor
>   so they take less space without the Navigation- and Tabbar.

Comment: That doesn’t *launch* the browser, it opens the current tab (read: browser already running).

Comment: This suited my needs perfectly; thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

To Expand on @Zuul answer with another way to specify Width/Height and x/y position for the window

This autohotkey script will do the trick too:

```
Run, C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k http://www.google.com/
WinWait, Windows Internet Explorer
WinMove,,,100,100,400,300
```

this example will position the window at x=100, y=100, with width=400 and height=300.

EDIT:Also

```
<body scroll="no">
```

in my html will disable(hide) the verticle scrollbar for IE. that + Zuul answer + this AHK script gets me to exactly where I was hoping.

EDIT2: Turns out I didn't even need the `scroll-"no"` in my html the vert scrollbar was never shown anyway. I imagine this is going to be dependent on what page you are showing though.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Nothing happens when I reload my AHK script.  The path is correct.

Comment: it definitely worked for me back when I needed it. Haven't touched it over a year though. Can't vouch for it with current IE versions. that being said, I can't think of a reason off the top of my head that would prevent it from working.

Comment: This is what I assumed I’d have to resort to (which is okay since it is an AHK script that is launching the website anyway), but then I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19789383/119540) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962811/119540). I’ll add the AHK method to my script as a comment in case Google decides to ruin the native options.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following extension ["Popup window" by Ett Chung](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popup-window/) in Firefox 
in combination with this Autohotkey script:

```
LWin & f::

WinGet Style, Style, A
if(Style & 0xC40000) {
  WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
  ;WinMaximize, A 

} else {
  WinSet, Style, +0xC40000, A
 ; WinRestore, A
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get Firefox to run in an (almost) borderless mode. There's just a thin bar at the top with the red/yellow/green blobs and page title (I use a Mac).

If I point the cursor to the top of the page, a drop-down strip appears with basic tools and address slot. Cursor down and it vanishes again.

BUT! It only works with Firefox 56. Updates after that refuse to work with my add-ons. In case you want to experiment they are: 'Hide Tab Bar With One Tab' and 'Toolbar Autohide'. I also use 'Menu Wizard' to  change the first menu item to 'Open in New Window' instead of tab.

Happy experimenting,

Ol.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Alex's answer: You can quickly add this to your `.bashrc` so you don't have to type/remember the whole command everytime

```
## run chrome w/o frame
chrome-no-frame(){
   chrome --app=$1
}
```

Then you can just copy the url and run `chrome-no-frame https://stackoverflow.com`

**** note that `https://` is required*

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this in a mac you can use [Pennywise](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/pennywise). It's a very basic browser, but it does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This 10 years old but I was looking for this also. There is an extension from Chrome & Edge, its called open as popup.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-as-popup/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc/related

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1186119)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## Firefox (since the end of 2019, version 71):

Basic kiosk mode:

`[install directory]\firefox.exe -kiosk`

Kiosk mode + url + private session:

`firefox.exe -kiosk -private-window [target URL]`

> ### What is Kiosk mode?
>
> Kiosk mode locks down Firefox in order to protect the kiosk from
> users. This is specifically relevant to, but not only limited to
> scenarios where the device is publicly accessed from libraries,
> vending machines or public transportation.
>
> Key characteristics of the Firefox Enterprise Kiosk mode:
>
> - Runs in full screen mode by default
> - All menus, awesome bar and toolbar are not visible as well as tabs
> - The X button is not available when you hover at the top of the screen
> - F11 does not work
> - The right-click context menu does not work
> - Hides the status bar at the the bottom when attempting to indicate progress
> - Hides the destination link when hovering over links
> - Available on Windows
>   Source: [Mozilla - Firefox Enterprise Kiosk mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode)