# Can I prevent users from closing a web browser window?

Tags: windows, windows-8, group-policy, desktop-management

I have a Windows 8 machine that will be setup in a training room. The training modules run through a web browser. I don't want the users to be able to close the browser or open any other programs, so I'm using group policies to prevent access to other programs, but I can't figure out a way to prevent the Browser from being closed. Is there a way I can accomplish that?

Comment: Also see [How can I launch a browser with no window frame or tabs/address bar](http://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kiosk mode for [Internet Explorer](http://www.ehow.com/how_6908457_open-ie-explorer-kiosk-mode.html).

`Start`, point to `Run`, and then type `iexplore -k <web address>`

> When you run Internet Explorer in Kiosk mode, the Internet Explorer title bar, menus, toolbars, and status bar are not displayed and Internet Explorer runs in Full Screen mode. The Windows taskbar is not displayed, but you can switch to other running programs by pressing ALT+TAB or CTRL+ALT+DEL. Because Internet Explorer is running in Full Screen mode, you cannot access the Windows desktop until you quit Internet Explorer.

Key combinations still work, but for the average application, this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google "kiosk mode" for your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Kruug's answer will probably suffice, but if you need a really secure kiosk, I'd check out http://www.sitekiosk.com