# Un-maximised browser in kiosk-style mode running on top

Tags: browser, kiosk

Let's say I want to have an [ISS webcam](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream) running on my desktop.  Is there any way to get any browser to run in a non-maximised window without menu clutter?  Specifically something equivalent to iexplorer's kiosk mode, but in a smaller window that stays on top of other windows.  Window should size to custom dimensions or automatically to webpage content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I launch a browser with no window frame or tabs/address bar](http://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar)

Comment: Some useful suggestions on that page, but not sure any of them manage to run on top.